# Reading Data Sent by Android Client using Servlet

Tags: android, servlets

I am sending data from android client to a server

```
httpPost.setEntity("Some String");
```

or

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

I want to retrieve this string or namevaluepairs or a hashmap.

I want to use a servlet instead of php scripting. I had looked at all methods of HttpRequest but missing something.

I am running the app in emulator with a tomcat local host and with 10.0.2.2 ip from emulator.

please provide a sample for such servlet. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet call `request.getParameter("parameterName")` to retrieve the parameters sent from your Android device.  The parameter name is the same name you use in your name/value pairs.

Assuming you are using a POST (if not, override `doGet` instead), your servlet should look like this:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      String value = request.getParameter("parameterName");

      ... more
  }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint to see the data you are receiving.  If the parameter is not present, it seems a problem in the Android side of your app.